# C Problem with the arrays( I think) || Programm for basic arithmetic operations N

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code...
I want to input N numbers, for example if my N is 4 I want to calculate 1 2 3 4 with 10 20 30 40.
(1 and 10, 2 and 20 etc. )
But my program calculates 1 and 2, 3 and 4, etc.
So what can I do that my array can calculate the input piece by piece.
(I want to keep the on Value and on reference Pointer for the calculate sub-programm)

Code:

```c
#define N 4
#include<stdio.h>

void KeyInput(double Input1[N]);
void KeyOutput(double Add[N], double Sub[N], double Mult[N], double Div[N]);
void calculate(double Input1[N], double Input2[N], double (*Add)[N],
        double (*Sub)[N], double (*Mult)[N], double (*Div)[N]);

int main() {
    int i;
    double Input1[N], Input2[N], Add[N], Sub[N], Mult[N],
            Div[N];

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        KeyInput(Input1);
        KeyInput(Input2);

        calculate(Input1, Input2, &Add, &Sub, &Mult, &Div);
        KeyOutput(Add, Sub, Mult, Div);
    }
    return 0;
}

void KeyInput(double Input1[N]) {
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%lf", &Input1[N]);
}

void calculate(double Input1[N], double Input2[N], double (*Add)[N],
        double (*Sub)[N], double (*Mult)[N], double (*Div)[N]) {

    (*Add)[N] = Input1[N] + Input2[N];
    (*Sub)[N] = Input1[N] - Input2[N];
    (*Mult)[N] = Input1[N] * Input2[N];
    (*Div)[N] = Input1[N] / Input2[N];
}

void KeyOutput(double Add[N], double Sub[N], double Mult[N], double Div[N]) {
    printf("Summe: %lf \t", Add[N]);
    printf("Differenz: %lf \t", Sub[N]);
    printf("Produkt: %lf \t", Mult[N]);
    printf("Quotient: %lf \n", Div[N]);
}
```

Comment: The explanation in the question requires  more improvement to be more clear and this can be done by **editing** the question.

Comment: `scanf("%lf", &Input1[N]);` cannot be correct. `N` is the size of the array, so you are accessing out of bounds

Comment: Since your `[N]` is so pervasive, why not `typedef` that and use that definition instead? What is a `double[4]` in this case, some kind of vector?

Comment: The more I Iook at this code the more I think `[N]` in every single case is a mistake and should be removed. You do calculations in a loop 4 times, but that's not to say every variable has to be 4-wide.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified and wrangled your code into a more conventional C form, where what you end up with is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

double key_input() {
    double input;

    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%lf", &input);

    return input;
}

void calculate(double input1, double input2, double *add,
    double *sub, double *mult, double *div) {

    *add = input1 + input2;
    *sub = input1 - input2;
    *mult = input1 * input2;
    *div = input1 / input2;
}

void key_output(double add, double sub, double mult, double div) {
    printf("Summe: %lf \t", add);
    printf("Differenz: %lf \t", sub);
    printf("Produkt: %lf \t", mult);
    printf("Quotient: %lf \n", div);
}

int main() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // Where practical just return values
        double input1 = key_input();
        double input2 = key_input();

        double add, sub, mult, div;
        calculate(input1, input2, &add, &sub, &mult, &div);
        key_output(add, sub, mult, div);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Once all the extraneous stuff, like the perplexing `[N]` stuff, is removed it's actually pretty straight-forward.

If you need to calculate multiple values in parallel you're going to need to explain in more detail what your intent is here. The original code is not set up to support that.

Notes here:

- Use simple variable names like `input` instead of `Input`.
- Don't use arrays unless your data is necessarily in array form.
- Avoid extra syntax whenever possible. `(*x) = y` can be reduced to `*x = y`.
- Define your functions before you use them to avoid having to declare and define separately.

Comment: In the last 7th line of the code, wouldn't `double add, sub, mult, div` declaration will happen time and again since it's iterating over loops? Would it not be better if we take those variables declared outsider of the loop?

Comment: @RohanBari They're only used inside the loop to move data from `calculate` to `key_output`, so I declared them in that scope to be clear. Declaring them is zero-cost, so performance-wise it doesn't matter, and even if it did, this is a loop run *four* times, so any hit is inconsequential.